# Excel Reference another sheet from within a function defined by a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok hopefully i can explain what i am needing to happen. So i have an Excel Document that keeps track of our staff members individual KPI's that is stored in their own sheet. What i am wanting to do is create a sheet that acts as the template for the monthly overview. So that when i enter the month into cell B3 and the staff members name into cell E3 it will goto the staff members sheet and get the required information from there.

Here is the formula i have so far that works well:

```
=INDEX('Jack'!F5:M84,MATCH(B3,'Jack'!A5:A84,0),MATCH(A6,'Jack'!F3:M3,0))
```

In the code above 'Jack' is the name of the staff members sheet - B3 is the month to search for - and A6 refers to the KPI i am looking for. I need to replace 'Jack' with the text that is entered into E3 so that i don't need to change the code for every staff member.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out the INDIRECT function.  I will try to make an answer that shows how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula. May be it will work for you.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(E3&"!F5:M84"),MATCH(B3,INDIRECT(E3&"!A5:A84"),0),MATCH(A6,INDIRECT(E3&"!F3:M3"),0))
```